# Perl: Accessing methods and json hashref data via the same object in class

Tags: perl, class

I have an object class, that extends JSON with file read and write functionality.
From the class usage perspective, I want to both use the methods of my class, and access the json hash with the same object.

For the example, I'll replace the file handling with from_json and to_json of a static string, but the principle would be the same.

My "user" code

```
use Extended::JSON;
my $config = Extended::JSON->open('{"Data":{"Property":"Data in json"}}');
print "Data from json: " . $config->{Data}->{Property} . "\n";
$config->{Data}->{Property} = 'New Data in json';
$config->write();
```

My class

```
use JSON;
package Extended::JSON;

sub open
{
  my $class = shift;
  my $data = shift;
  my self = { _jsonhash => from_json( $data ) };
  };
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}
sub write
{
  my $self = shift;
  print to_json( $self->{_jsonhash} );
}
```

As you see, the "user" code should be able to use the class attributes to directly access and change the returing hash from from_json, but the methods should act as for the class.
I'm missing, if it is possible to somewhere universally "wrap" the attribute access to a class method to change the json hash, not the object attributes.

Thanks you!
Christian

Comment: Do you need to store anything else in the object? Your sample code doesn't show anything else. If not, why not just have the object be the data itself, instead of a hashref with a `_jsondata` key that stores the data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. When I return the json hash to the "user" code, I cannot access the methods of the class anymore. 
In the class, I store the content of the initial string, to determine later in the write method, if the data have changed (only really write on change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class has no attributes (object variables), you can use the variable returned by `from_json` as the object.

```
package Extended::JSON;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use JSON qw( from_json to_json );

sub open {
   my ($class, $json) = @_;
   return bless(from_json($json), $class);
}

sub write {
   my ($self) = @_;
   say to_json($self);
}

1;
```

You can still use that approach if the class has attributes by hiding them when it comes time to regenerate the JSON.

```
package Extended::JSON;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use JSON qw( from_json to_json );

sub open {
   my ($class, $json) = @_;
   my $self = bless(from_json($json), $class);
   # $self->{_foo} = ...;
   return $self;
}

sub write {
   my ($self) = @_;
   delete local @$self{ grep /^_/, keys(%$self) };
   say to_json($self);
}

1;
```

The above requires the top-level of the JSON to be an "object" (hash), and it prevents certain keys from being used in that object. To avoid those limitations, we can use [overload](https://metacpan.org/pod/overload).

```
package Extended::JSON;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use JSON qw( from_json to_json );

use overload '%{}' => \&data;

sub open {
   my ($class, $json) = @_;
   my $self = bless(\{}, $class);
   $$self->{data} = from_json($json);
   # $$self->{foo} = ...;
   return $self;
}

sub write {
   my ($self) = @_;
   say to_json($$self->{data});
}

sub data {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return $$self->{data};
}

1;
```

The above creates a scalar-based object (as opposed to a hash-based object). Treating the reference as a hash reference gets the data obtained from the JSON, while treating the reference as a scalar reference gets the "real" object.

```
$ perl -e'
   use Extended::JSON qw( );
   my $o = Extended::JSON->open(q{{"a":123}});
   CORE::say $o->{a};
   $o->write;
'
123
{"a":123}
```

Comment: This was really eye-opening - thanks very much for the examples!